# Angular2 Output Eventemitter is only working on Plunkr but not working when using local copy

Tags: angular

I've been trying this angular2 sample [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent) using plunkr and it is working fine, but if i use visual studio 2015/Code and download all package(node_modules) somehow is not working properly, i have attached the sample local copy that the first "Agree/disagree" emit is not working only the 2nd/3rd is working.

Here is my code copy: [SampleApplication](https://github.com/angular/angular/files/523574/AngularEventEmitterTest.zip)

Hope someone can help me on this thanks.

Comment: link on plunkr copy: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ia9bg4IhScRvGTXj3dRa?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry folks, already figured it out what is the problem.

it's my module declaration and i should remove the votercomponent in the bootstrap

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [VoteTakerComponent, VoterComponent],
    bootstrap: [VoteTakerComponent, VoterComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```